# Angular return value from another column by using the index of maximum value in a array

Tags: angular

I'm trying to find the lowest value in each column and return the item with in lowest value in each column. Then in third footer looking for count of values less than 10. Since i'm new to Angular, finding it difficult to find an example.

I made a sample code at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multiple-footer-f44hva?file=src/app/app.component.ts) and required format in image
below,

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the working at [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multiple-footer-udtagn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

The below function will return the total of items below 10

```
  countMinItem(columnName: string) {
    columnName = columnName.replace('f2_', '').replace('f3_', '');
    return this.transactions
      .map(t => t[columnName])
      .reduce((acc, val) => (val < 10 ? acc + 1 : acc), 0);
  }
```

Comment: I need only the count of values less than 10. So what change i need to do?

Comment: @KennyJohnJoseph, I have updated the code.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav.... regarding finding the lowest value and its item name, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To find the lowest value and item from each column you can use following method

```js
getMinValue(transactions: Transaction[], columnName: string) {
    if (transactions.length == 0) {
        return {};
    }
    minTransaction = transactions[0];
    transactions.forEach(trans => {
        if (trans[columnName] < minTransaction[columnName]) {
            minTransaction = trans;
        }
    });
    return minTransaction;
}
```

You can use this method as follows to find lowest value and item for `cost` column:

```js
let minTransaction = getMinValue(transactions, 'cost');
// minTransaction = { item: 'Frisbee', cost: 2, a: 10, b: 12 }
console.log("item name: ", minTransaction.item);  // output: Frisbee
console.log("item value: ", minTransaction.cost);  // output: 2
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit. I just made small change to your code. Now its perfectly working for dynamic column using below code,
```javascript
getMinItem(columnName: any) {
    columnName = columnName.replace('f2_', '').replace('f3_', '');
    if (this.transactions.length == 0) {
        return {};
    }
    var minTransaction = this.transactions[0];
    this.transactions.forEach(trans => {
        if (trans[columnName] < minTransaction[columnName]) {
            minTransaction = trans;
        }
    });
    return minTransaction.item;
  }```

Comment: If my solution code helped you, please do upvote it.